# Select Day From Form to Change Where Clause

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a report query in Access 2010 that lets users see the forecast of estimated shipments coming in today. A request a user had for me was that I make a form that allows them to also see forecasts for the entire week(Mon-Fri) or they can select a date and then see the forecast for that future date.

So essentially I want to make a form that users can select the day of the week or use a datepicker to pick a specific date. And then utilize vba to change the where clause of my SQL to produce a report for that day.

My assumption was to use a Listbox populated with the days of the week but for some reason I feel like I'm approaching this wrong. Any guidance or suggestions on approaching developing this.

Update**
[image]

I apologize for the image size. Like I said I want the user to select the day of the week in the listbox and then when they click to view the query it changes the where clause based on the value selected.

Comment: I like the DatePicker idea. With the ListBox they'd have to select also a week or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the DatePicker.  All you need to do is have the SQL get built on-the-fly with something like this:

```
Dim strSQL as String
Dim qd As QueryDef

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyDateField = '#" & Me.txtMyDate & "#'"

Set qd = CurrentDB.CreateQueryDef("MyReportQuery", strSQL)
```

You should now have a query called MyReportQuery, which you can use as the RecordSource for your report.  The good news is, you can hard-code that RecordSet name because you're going to re-create it every time it's run.  Just don't forget to put some code in that checks to see if the query already exists, and if so it deletes it.

**EDIT:** For the record, many Access MVP's actually suggest you delete an existing query by doing this:

```
On Error Resume Next
CurrentDB.QueryDefs.Delete "MyReportQuery"
On Error GoTo 0 ' or your own error-handler
```

If the query exists, it will be deleted.  if it doesn't, the Resume Next will force the code to ignore the error and continue.  You then reset the On Error to go to your own error handler.  And if you don't have an error handler in your code, you're doing it wrong.  :o)